# How do I sort this JSON Object by price in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have a JSON object that I'd like to sort by price from least to greatest.

```
{
 "BEY": {
  "1": {
    "price": 2280,
    "airline": "QR",
  },
  "2": {
    "price": 2108,
    "airline": "UA",
  }
 },
 "BKK": {
  "1": {
    "price": 2956,
    "airline": "QR",
  },
  "2": {
    "price": 1718,
    "airline": "WS",
  }
 }
}
```

I'd like to re-format it so that the key is the price of the airplane ticket. For example:

```
{ 
  1718: {
   "airline" : "WS",
   "IATA_Code" : "BKK"
  },
  2108: {
   "airline" : "UA",
   "IATA_Code" : "BEY"
  },
  2280: {
   "airline" : "QR",
   "IATA_Code" : "BEY"
  },
  2956: {
   "airline" : "QR",
   "IATA_Code" : "BKK"
  }
}
```

Comment: Objects are unordered. You'll have to change the data structure into an array to begin with. (Or do some very creative bending over backwards when iterating this object.)

Comment: What if two tickets have the same price? BTW, a "JSON object" is a wrong name for a JavaScript object. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130836/discussion-on-question-by-areyoufried-how-do-i-sort-this-json-object-by-price-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three issues that prevent you from accomplishing this task.

1. You are going to have to crawl over the object and sub-objects to extract the key-values that you need.
2. Also, you cannot sort an object of objects. You can do this with an array instead. I converted your structure to an object array.
3. You will not be able to parse your JSON properly until you remove those stray commas following your `"airline"` values. Refer to the valid JSON inside the text area element.

So, before you begin converting your JSON, you need to use [JSLint](http://jsonlint.com/) or another tool built on top of it (JSHint, etc...) and verify that your JSON is; indeed valid.

```js
var inputJSON = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json-data').value);
var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(convert(inputJSON), null, 4);

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + outputJSON + '</pre>';

function convert(data) {
  var result = [];
  Object.keys(data).forEach(function(code) {
    Object.keys(data[code]).forEach(function(ticket) {
      var record = {
        'IATA_Code': code
      };
      Object.keys(data[code][ticket]).forEach(function(key) {
        record[key] = data[code][ticket][key];
      });
      result.push(record);
    });
  });
  return result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.price > b.price;
  });
};
```

```html
<textarea id="json-data">
{
  "BEY": {
    "1": { "price": 2280, "airline": "QR" },
    "2": { "price": 2108, "airline": "UA" }
  },
  "BKK": {
    "1": { "price": 2956, "airline": "QR" },
    "2": { "price": 1718, "airline": "WS" }
  }
}
</textarea>
```

Valid JSON result after clicking: <kbd>**▶ Run code snippet**</kbd> button above.

```
[{
  "IATA_Code": "BKK",
  "price": 1718,
  "airline": "WS"
}, {
  "IATA_Code": "BEY",
  "price": 2108,
  "airline": "UA"
}, {
  "IATA_Code": "BEY",
  "price": 2280,
  "airline": "QR"
}, {
  "IATA_Code": "BKK",
  "price": 2956,
  "airline": "QR"
}]
```

Comment: Your `data` is not JSON; it is a Javascript object. You didn't answer the question, sorry. -1

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I never used the term JSON, in my response. I know this is a JavaScript object. So, I have no clue what you're referring to. The question was how can the data be transformed to such-and-such structure and then sorted by price.

Comment: _"I never used the term JSON, in my response. I know this is a JavaScript object. So, I have no clue what you're referring to."_ The question says "JSON" several times, in the title, the body and the tags. Helps to read it before answering :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, I migrated the JSObject to a JSON string and placed it inside a text area. I noted the invalid JSON syntax (stray commas).

Comment: It's better now :-)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to think of what your output data structure will be when you have multiple entries with the same price. As you want the price to be the key, that is not possible, unless you foresee to store an array for each key: then you can store one, two or more entries for the same price.

For that you could use this ES6 code. The `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` methods are of course not needed if you have the object "living" in JavaScript already:

```js
var obj = JSON.parse(`{
 "BEY": {
  "1": {
    "price": 2280,
    "airline": "QR"
  },
  "2": {
    "price": 2108,
    "airline": "UA"
  }
 },
 "BKK": {
  "1": {
    "price": 2956,
    "airline": "QR"
  },
  "2": {
    "price": 1718,
    "airline": "WS"
  }
 }
}`);

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acc, IATA_Code) =>
    Object.keys(obj[IATA_Code]).reduce( (acc, i) => {
        let price = obj[IATA_Code][i].price;
        acc[price] = (acc[price] || []).concat({
            airline: obj[IATA_Code][i].airline, 
            IATA_Code 
        });
        return acc;
    }, acc),
{});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your `obj` is not JSON; it is a Javascript object. You didn't answer the question, sorry. -1

Comment: Added JSON parsing in the answer although the OP probably spoke about JavaScript objects, not JSON. The OP's example is not valid JSON anyway.

Comment: Better now. _"The JSON.parse and JSON.stringify methods are of course not needed if you have the object "living" in JavaScript already"_ still blurs the lines between JSON and objects by implying that JSON can live in JavaScript as a literal (it can't)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thank you for your comment, but I speak of the object, the thing that resides in memory, not the notation. Of course I agree that JSON is incompatible with JavaScript object literals, and the OP's notation is an example of such incompatibility.

Comment: There is no such thing "residing in memory". JSON is a text interchange format. Once it has been parsed, it is not JSON any more; it is whatever you parsed it into. In your code, that is a JavaScript object.

Comment: We are talking about different things. I am *not* talking about JSON when I speak of *"residing in memory"* (where did I say it was JSON?), that is why I added that I did *not* speak of "*the notation*". Indeed, the JavaScript object is what I refer to when I speak of *"object"*.

Comment: Okay, that's good then.